# Predicate Logic expressions - are the equivalent?

Tags: logic

Are the following expressions equivalent?

```
¬∃x(student(x) ∧ learn(x))
∀x(student(x) ∧ learn(x))
¬∀x(student(x) ∧ learn(x))
```

Comment: I see that `∃x(teacher(x) ∧ senseofhumor(x))`. If only it were `∀x`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that you have several expressions of quantified logic which all share the same predicate:

```
(student(x) ∧ learn(x))
```

We can just replace this predicate with a single combined predicate:

```
P(x) = (student(x) ∧ learn(x)).
```

Regarded this way, your question boils down to this: are these equivalent?

```
¬∃x P(x)
∀x P(x)
¬∀x P(x)
```

You can see that the P(x) is not important at all since it is a common element; you're asking whether the *quantifiers themselves* are equivalent.

We can look at all three possible pairs of these to show they are not.

1. Obviously ∀ is the logical opposite of ¬∀.
2. ¬∃ is mutually exclusive with ∀: if there does not exist even one instance, how can there exist all?
3. Finally ¬∀ and ¬∃ are not the same either. One means "not all" and the other means "none".

In summary: "none", "all" and "not all" are different quantifiers.

**Another thing**

Note that all our expressions have a free variable. No, not `x` of course, but the function `P`.  So what we are saying here is that for all possible instantiations of the function `P`, those quantifiers are not equivalent. However, we could instantiate `P` such that some of the expressions are equivalent.

For instance if we were to forget about `student(x) ∧ learn(x)` and take `P(X) = (x == x)`. The predicate asserts that x is equal to itself.  When we plug this into `∀x P(x)` we now have something in which all variables are instantiated and bound, and so we can evaluate it down to a single truth value. Yes, for all X, it is true that X is equal to itself! So this statement is true. Next, `¬∀x P(x)` is false since it asserts that not all X's are equal to themselves. And `¬∃x P(x)` is also false since it asserts that no X is equal to itself.  Since `¬∀x P(x)` and `¬∃x P(x)` are both false, they are equivalent (under the given instantiation of the function `P`, not in general for any function `P`!)

In logic we always have to keep in mind whether we are talking about the formulas themselves, or concrete instantiations in which symbols are substituted with concretes, or something in between: partial instantiations in which some symbols are substituted with instances, and others free.

Two formulas may not be equivalent (in the sense that we can find a combination of variables which instantiate them and yield a different truth value). But instantiations can be equivalent (yield the same truth value, or the same truth value for all *remaining* instantiations of variables hitherto not instantiated).

Answer (score 4):

No. See [Wikipedia: De_Morgan's_laws#Extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Extensions).
$$ \lnot \exists x (S(x) \land L(x)) \equiv \forall x \lnot (S(x) \land L(x)) \\
 \lnot \forall x (S(x) \land L(x)) \equiv \exists x \lnot (S(x) \land L(x)) \\
$$
Also, by De Morgan's again:
$$ \lnot (S(x) \land L(x)) \equiv (\lnot S(x) \lor \lnot L(x)) $$

Answer (score 3):

No formalism should be required to see that they are not equivalent. In plain English, the first one says that there is nothing that is a student who learns. (I used *nothing* instead of *no one* to allow for the possibility that the domain of discourse includes things that aren’t people.) The second says that everything in the domain of discourse is a student who learns. And the third says that it’s not the case that everything in the domain of discourse is a student who learns, or in other words, there is something that is not a student who learns (either because it’s not a student, or because it doesn’t learn, or both).

In particular, the last two are clearly incompatible: one is the negation of the other, so exactly one of them can be true.

Comment: Careful, careful! "In plain English" might lead you astray when dealing with formal logic (although not here, of course).

Comment: @chx: True, but in elementary settings it’s a useful starting point, even if you have to go on to find a formal justification.